# convert a formula into string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a big spreadsheet with hundreds of cells and every cell contains a formula. I would like these formulas to be returned as string. For example, if a cell contains this formula
countif(A1:50,A1) and this returns a value of 5. What i want is instead of getting the result of the formula is to get the formula as a string "countif(A1:50,A1)"
Can anyone help?

Comment: [FORMULATEXT()](https://exceljet.net/functions/formulatext-function) - assuming you're using Excel 2013 or later

Comment: or if you want to see them in the cells hit [ctrl]-[`]

Comment: I often just do a find/replace and replace the "=" with "xyxy" then all is text. Also easily reversed.